# Topology on ideles

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, adeles

I am new to adeles and ideles in number fields. I am trying to solve Exercise 2 in [this pdf](http://www.math.u-psud.fr/~ratazzi/montd8_9.pdf).

This is a very standard fact the statement of which can be found in any textbook. I have done exercise 2 part 1. I am stuck with exercise 2 part 2 and 3. It will be very helpful if someone gives me a solution in detail. Please help...

Comment: It would be nice for us mono-language people if you would post an English translation of the entire exercise as part of your question.

Comment: @rogerl: Learning enough mathematical French to be able to read those exercises is a good task if you are interested in number theory.

Comment: @KCd Oh, I can read it just fine. But at least the question should have been posted rather than linked to on the site...